# Firebase - Security Rule Restricting Write to Node Owner/Creator

Tags: firebase-security

In the screenshot below, my `details` branch/node contains lots of details named with a random-id.  As shown in the example, `8641260c-900...` is a detail record and there will be several others like these.

**I would like to know whether my `.write` rule is correct or not?** I wanted to enable restriction so that current `auth.id` exactly match the existing record's `user` field.

I would also wanted to restrict deletion of the record (via `.remove`).
**Can I simply add `&& !data.exists() || newData.exists()` to the `.write` rule?**

Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know whether my .write rule is correct or not?

First of all, giving `".read":true` and `".write":true` to the root will override all child node rules to `true`. Therefore any rules specified to child nodes will become redundant.

> I wanted to enable restriction so that current auth.id exactly match the existing record's user field.

```
{"rules":{
    "existing_record":{
        "user":{
            ".write":"newData.isString() && auth.uid == newData.val()"
        }
    }
}}
```

> I would also wanted to restrict deletion of the record (via .remove).

`newData.exists()` will prevent deletion of a node. **newData** represents how data will look like after the operation took place. Therefore, by ensuring that **newData** exists after the operation, deletion of a node is prohibited.